# Rx extension to keep generating events for N seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

What is the right Rx extension method (in .NET) to keep generating events for N seconds?

By 'keep generating events for N seconds' I mean that it will keep generating events in a loop since DateTime.Now till DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(N)

I'm working on genetic algorithm that will generate number of hypotheses and propagate the most successful ones to the next generation. Need to constrain this guy in some elegant way.

**Added later:**

I've actually realized that I need to do pull instead of push and came-up with something like this:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Pull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int? times = null)
    {
        if (times == null) 
            return enumerable.ToArray();
        else
            return enumerable.Take(times.Value).ToArray();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Pull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, TimeSpan timeout, int? times = null)
    {
        var start = DateTime.Now;

        if (times != null) enumerable = enumerable.Take(times.Value);

        using (var iterator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (DateTime.Now < start + timeout && iterator.MoveNext())
                yield return iterator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

And usage would be:

```
var results = lazySource.SelectMany(item =>
{
    //processing goes here
}).Pull(timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), times: numberOfIterations);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may well be a cleaner way of doing this, but you could use:

```
// This will generate events repeatedly
var interval = Observable.Interval(...);

// This will generate one event in N seconds
var timer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(N));

// This will combine the two, so that the interval stops when the timer
// fires
var joined = interval.TakeUntil(timer);
```

It's been a long time since I've done any Rx, so I apologise if this is incorrect - but it's worth a try...

Comment: Jon is spot on, as usual; you could also craft a custom stream with Observable.Create. Also, timeout does throw if the timeout window has exceeded without a signal on the governing stream.

Comment: @JerKimball: Ah, but it doesn't throw (and stop the stream) if the original stream is still producing? In that case it wouldn't be good...

Comment: As the answer is probably the correct one - I've suddenly realized that it's better to use 'pull' instead of 'push' in my specific case, because it feels more naturally to keep pulling hypotheses from processing pipeline than pushing and then subscribing. But your answer definitely helped me to understand what I really want to do!

Comment: Yeah, the error condition isn't triggered so long as the event on the trigger stream comes within the specified time.

Comment: Looks good, though always specify an explicit scheduler for Observable.Timer, and I'd inline the 'timer' variable.

Comment: @PaulBetts: I'd probably inline stuff normally, but this is for exposition :)

Comment: @JerKimball: Thanks - I'll get rid of the bit about Timeout then as it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Jon's post is pretty much spot on, however I noticed your edit where you suggested you would create your own extension methods to do this. I think it would be better* if you just used the built in operators.

```
//LinqPad sample
void Main()
{
    var interval = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));  
    var maxTime = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    IEnumerable<int> lazySource = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);

    lazySource.ToObservable()
            .Zip(interval, (val, tick)=>val)
            .TakeUntil(maxTime)
            .Dump();
}
```

*ie. easy for other devs to maintain and understand